# Simple Model Help For A CNN python

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am really struggling with the basic concepts. Would anyone be able to help me make a simple model that only consists of two Conv2D layers and one fully connected layers. Both convolutional layers only use 16 kernels. So it would be Conv2D,Conv2D, fully , fully, softmax. This project is to detect eight different types of trees. Thanks If my question is stupid or doesn't make sense its okay I will keep trying. Thank you

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# To stop potential randomness
seed = 42
rng = np.random.RandomState(seed)

data = pd.read_csv('../datasets/Tree_classification/classification.csv')

# load images and store it in numpy array
X = []
for img_name in data.image_names:
    img = plt.imread('../datasets/classification/images/' + img_name)
    X.append(img)

X=np.array(X)

# create target
y = data.Tree_or_not.values

X.shape

X = X / X.max()

X_train, X_valid, Y_train, Y_valid=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

model = Sequential()

model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(245, 245, 3)))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=(1, 1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=(1, 1), padding='valid'))

model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units=9, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(X_valid,Y_valid))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you run it? Skimming through, I'd say you can 1) add `batch_size=24` in `model.fit()`, 2) use `'softmax'` activation function in your last dense layer, 3) use `'relu'` activation function in your first dense layer, 4) use `'categorical_crossentropy'` as your loss function.

Comment: Okay thank you so much for the reply. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: To get it to read more than one class, do I just write the class number [0]-[7] in the csv file? Then in the model.fit add the class labels? And is my target okay?

Answer (score 0):

You might find it useful to look at an example using CNNs from the Keras documentation:  https://keras.io/examples/cifar10_cnn/ .  In particular, note the use of the Flatten() layer before the final Dense layers.  You can probably ignore the "data_augmentation" part of the example.  Additionally, you can always use the "model.summary()" to see what your model architecture is as you build it out.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help